# emacs Tramp on Windows: plink says /bin/sh: env: command not found

Tags: windows, emacs, plink, tramp

Using emacs Tramp on Windows, I am trying to remotely log in to a windows PC. It issues following plink command which fails (both on emacs and cmd.exe)

While putty gives me a session. I would want to use it via emacs. 
What do I need to do to make it work on Tramp on Windows.

*Note: I have tried the byte-compile-file tramp-sh.el fix as mentioned in one SO answer. updated to using Emacs 26.1 via Git MSys2 (minimal cygwin, we could say). Referred to few more answers and did not find much help for target windows PC. Any help pointer is appreciated.*

**cmd.exe:**

```
C:\Users\myUser>plink -v -l int***** -ssh -t inpu******* " env 'TERM=dumb' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=
#$ ' ssh " && exit | exit
... 
...
Sent password
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
Started a shell/command
/bin/sh: env: command not found
Server sent command exit status 0
Disconnected: All channels closed
```

**Emacs:**

```
Tramp: Opening connection for int*****@inpu******* using plink...
Tramp: Sending command ‘plink -l int*****  -ssh -t inpu******* " env 'TERM=dumb' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=#$ ' /bin/sh " && exit || exit’
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...
Tramp: Sending password
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
Tramp: Opening connection for int*****@inpu******* using plink...failed
```

**Update 1:** Using MSys2 instead of /bin/sh just exits *(expected to start a shell session using MSys2)*

```
Sent password
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
Started a shell/command
*exits here*
```

Answer (score 2):

Tramp expects "/bin/sh" as remote shell. See variable `tramp-methods`, entry "plink", attribute `tramp-login-program`. You could change this (the Tramp manual explains), but whatever you choose, it must be a POSIX compatible shell. No idea, whether there is such a beast on  MS Windows.

Comment: I maybe lame but can [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/) available from [git for windows sdk](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/releases/) be considered a POSIX compatible shell on MS Windows ?

Comment: Perhaps MSYS2 shell cold be good enough. Don't know, I don't use MS Windows myself. I do expect further problems (used POSIX tools, MS Windows style path names vs UNIX style path names, etc). Best you try it.

Comment: I tried on cmd.exe it just exits :( (updated answer). I have one more option to try on windows 10 (the subshell) after which I finally quit and use GNU/Linux in VM.

Comment: ah wait, guess I have to add MSys2 on the Guest Windows as well. right?

Comment: Sure, we're speaking 'bout running the shell at the remote host.